# Use of MKMapView with MKMapTypeSatellite with country borders but without other labels and text?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

Is it somehow possible to use MKMapView with MKMapTypeSatellite with country borders alone to see countries but without labels and text (country name's, city name's)? When I use MKMapTypeHybrid the borders are shown but also the labels of countries and cities are shown..

Or is it somehow possible to use MKMapView with MKMapTypeStandard without labels and text (country name's, city name's)?